# How to change the properties of Launch image in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I had an iPhone application in which I am using an image Default-568h@2x.png as the lauchimage or splash screen.

Also at the same time I am setting the same image to an image view to the window for some animation on the splash screen. My image has an opacity of 90%.

The problem here is before our own image view comes to the window the launch image is showing with 100% opacity, then our own image view comes up with actual 90%. So there is notable transition in the two images with in the fraction of seconds. Not going very well with this, can we avoid this, why my launch image is showing with full opacity at first? Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps always launch with the image set to full opacity - you can't change that.  If you want to match your initial screen to your launch image, you have two options:

1) Make the image have full opacity; then in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you could do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

    self.imageView.alpha = 0.9;

}];
```

So once your app has finished launching, your image will fade to 90% opacity.

2) Work out what will be underneath the image after your app launches, then precompose the launch image with that; so that it appears the same.  You could do this by launching your app, waiting for the current launch image to go away, then taking a screenshot of the running app and using that screenshot as your new launch image.

Comment: so the effect will be same is it?first image with full opacity then with 90%.the same is happening now also

Comment: the problem here is not about opacity of the image view,why my original image is not showing in the launch,my image has only 90%opacity.

Comment: The opacity of your launch image will be ignored. You can't change that; you'll just have to work around it.

Comment: I've added another option - faking the transparency in the launch image.

Answer (score -2):

Change the image name to something else like, Splash.png

Now compiler could not find any default launch image for your application.

Then it will directly try to load your window. So load your image/view over window with required animation.

**OR**

Use Default-568h image which already has a lesser opacity (using photoshop type of tools), let say 90%. Now add one more image, splash.png with opacity 100%. So when your code runs, it will first convert splash.png to 90% opacity then imply your animation code.

So, there won't be any lagging between Default image and Splash image, both will look same alike.